# How to print an array element that is found in a string C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So I am looking at a string, and seeing if it contains one of the elements that appears in an array. Then I want to output the element in the array that matches what is in the string. If the string contains two elements or more from the array, then it will output all elements from the array it contains. When I do the output part, it only outputs the first element in the array, regardless of which element in the array matches with something in the string. My code is below, would greatly appreciate it if you could help me understand what I am doing wrong!

```
string nouns[] = { "MAILBOX", "KNIFE", "TROLL", "THIEF", "LETTER", "OPPONENT" };
string command = "THE LETTER IS IN THE MAILBOX.";
//check if each command has one of the nouns
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        if (command.find(nouns[j])){
            string foundnound = nouns[j];
            cout << "The noun is: " << foundnound << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Give us http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See [cppreference - std::basic_string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: You should check the return value of `find` against `string::npos`.

Comment: In addition to the [`npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) commented above, if you want to `cout` all found nouns, you need to remove the `break` inside the `if`. With the `break` it will stop the `for` after finding the 1st one

Comment: Please do not rewrite your question to ask a completely different question. Doing so invalidates the answers given. Instead, you should ask a new question, using the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context. I have rolled back your question to the way it was phrased when you accepted Angel Diaz's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

`if (command.find(nouns[j]))`

That says, as long as the return value of `find()` is not `0`, then execute the code inside the if statement. 
When no match is found, `find` returns the maximum value for size_t, which is not zero.

Check out the reference for the `find` function.
[std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Comment: also, if you want to check for more than one match, remove the `break`, you don't want to exit the for loop after the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're searching for the nouns in order, if the input contains MAILBOX, it will return that, regardless of where it appears in the command.  If you want to print the first word in the command that matches one of the nouns, they you need to split the command into words, and iterate through those, seeing if the word in command is in the noun list.

Comment: Thank you everyone! This definitely helped solve my problems!

Answer (score 0):

`c++11` (not optimal of course, but small):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
using std::string;

int main() {
  string nouns[] = {"MAILBOX", "KNIFE", "TROLL", "THIEF", "LETTER", "OPPONENT"};
  string command = "THE LETTER IS IN THE MAILBOX.";

  std::copy_if(std::begin(nouns), std::end(nouns),
               std::ostream_iterator<string>(std::cout, "\n"),
               [&command](const std::string &noun) {
                 return command.find(noun) != std::string::npos;
               });
}
```

Comment: @elastic-g if do not want to print duplicates, then use  `std::copy_if` with `insert_iteartor` and `std::set` , and after that output `std::set`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what you mean. I just learned this stuff yesterday and it is still very confusing to me